# How to optimize function to get highest coefficient in linear regression?

Tags: regression

I am building a typical linear multivariate regression, except that one of variables, rather than being a simple data point, is a function dependent on one of the other variables. So for example, my regression may look like:

y1=c1*x1+c2*x2+c3*x3+c4*f(x3)

f itself contains coefficients a,b,c,d

*This particular function is of the form, f(x)=a - b/(1 + e^(-c*(x-d)))

Basically, the point of my research is to find which values of a, b, c, and d lead to the highest value of x4, and, hopefully, the best model.

I'm pretty inexperienced in R, but my advisor told me he thinks it would be the best program to get this kind of thing done in... Anyone have any advice on where to start with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out non linear least squares. For R implementation see [nls](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html)